# Visual Studio having problems importing jaxws schema

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm currently running into problems after upgrading my jaxws service to the latest version of apache cxf.  My visual studio project cannot update its web service references without getting an error "".

here's my wsdl, which seems to be the source of the problem:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ingestion.webservice.musicnet.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="ingestion" targetNamespace="http://ingestion.webservice.musicnet.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" version="1.0">

            <xs:complexType final="#all" name="intArray">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType final="#all" name="stringArray">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" xmlns="http://ingestion.webservice.musicnet.com/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://ingestion.webservice.musicnet.com/">
            <xs:import/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array"/>
            <xs:element name="component" type="Component"/>
            <xs:element name="delivery" type="qDelivery"/>
            <xs:complexType name="WorkItemFilter">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="pageNumber" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mediaType" type="MediaType"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockFilter" type="LockFilter"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="contentSupplier" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="priority" type="xs:int"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="XmlErrorWorkItemSearchResultSet">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="pageNumber" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="totalItems" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="workItem" type="XmlErrorWorkItem"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="XmlErrorWorkItem">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="compTypeId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xmlFile" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockObtainedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastUpdatedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="CatalogArtist">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="artistSortName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="artistCategory" type="ArtistCategory"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="amgIdCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="muzeId" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastUpdatedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="DupWorkItemResultSet">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="pageNumber" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="totalItems" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="workItems" nillable="true" type="DupWorkItem"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="DupWorkItem">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="compTypeId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockObtainedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastUpdatedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="compCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="artist" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="paIndicator" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element name="numberTracks" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="releaseDates" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="approvedTerritories" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="revokedTerritories" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="relatedUPC" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ingestedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="dupMatches" nillable="true" type="DupMatch"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="DupMatch">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dupCompCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="dupCompId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dupState" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="matchType" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="notes" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="owner" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="artist" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="paIndicator" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element name="numberTracks" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="releaseDates" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ingestionDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="approvedTerritories" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="revokedTerritories" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="relatedUPC" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Component">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="parentId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="compCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="compId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="parentCompCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="compType" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="compSubtype" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="supplierCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="contentOwner" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="exclusiveRetailerList" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xmlFileName" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xmlDeliveryLocation" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="behavior" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="imageUri" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="manualEdited" type="xs:boolean"/>
                            <xs:element name="repackageInd" type="xs:boolean"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="context" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="concurrencyDbVersionDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="metadata" nillable="true" type="Metadata"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="artist" type="Artist"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="artistMetadata" nillable="true" type="ArtistMetadata"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="right" type="Right"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="cost" type="Cost"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="collection" type="Collection"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="file" type="ComponentFile"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="packagedFile" type="PackagedFile"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="childComponent" type="Component"/>
                            <xs:element name="copiedFromDbComp" type="xs:boolean"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="rightsShare" type="qRightsShare"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="timeStampedObject">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastUpdatedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Metadata">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="exValue" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="territoryCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="manualEdited" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Artist">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplementalText" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="seqNbr" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="assignedArtistId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="manualEdited" type="xs:boolean"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="matchedIds" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ArtistMetadata">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="exValue" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="artistName" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="assignedArtistId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="manualEdited" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Right">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="effectiveFrom" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="effectiveTo" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="territoryCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="retailerCode" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Cost">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="scope" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="productOfferCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="territoryCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="currencyCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="costCategory" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="rpCategory" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="amount" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="reqRetailPrice" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="suggestedRetailPrice" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="effectiveFrom" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="effectiveTo" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="retailerCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="costSourceCode" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Collection">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="relatedCompId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="compCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="providerCompId" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="seqNbr" type="xs:int"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ComponentFile">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="filename" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="currentFilename" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sourcePath" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="repositoryCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fileSize" type="xs:int"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="PackagedFile">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="timeStampedObject">
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="componentFilesId" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="fileGuid" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mediaHash" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="filename" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="contentKey" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="licenseAquisitionUrl" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="fileSize" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="playBitRate" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="licenseableInd" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="activeStatusCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="publishActionCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="contentId" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="videoSize" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="assetCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="durationSecs" type="xs:int"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="qRightsShare">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="administratorName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="controllerName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="isValid" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="percentageRate" type="xs:double"/>
                    <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="territoryCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="validityPeriod" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="SubmitResult">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" type="ComponentStatus"/>
                    <xs:element name="workItemId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="assetLocation" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="errors" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="QCWorkItemResultSet">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="pageNumber" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="totalItems" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="workItems" nillable="true" type="QCWorkItem"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="QCWorkItem">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="compTypeId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="compCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="quarantineId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockObtainedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastUpdatedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="releaseDate" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="artist" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="subtaskType" type="SubtaskType"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="errors" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ReevaluateDupResultSet">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="workItem" type="DupWorkItem"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="reevalResults" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="CompMatch">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="duplicateComponentCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="duplicateComponentId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="duplicateSupplierCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="friendlySupplier" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="duplicateSource" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="matchType" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="DupRelatedItemResultSet">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="pageNumber" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="totalItems" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="dupMatchItems" nillable="true" type="DupMatch"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="GenericWorkItem">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="compTypeId" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="taskType" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="subtaskType" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="referenceKey" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="details" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lockObtainedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastUpdatedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="qDelivery">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="component" type="Component"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleType name="MediaType">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="MUSIC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MUSIC_VIDEO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TV_SHOW"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MOVIE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EBOOK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="COLLECTION"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType name="LockFilter">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="ALL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ACCESSIBLE_BY_USER"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NOT_LOCKED"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LOCKED_BY_USER"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType name="ArtistCategory">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="MOVIE_TV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MUSIC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EBOOK"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType name="ComponentStatus">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="PROMOTED"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="QUARANTINE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="DUPLICATE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="REVIEW"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ERROR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="REJECTED"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType name="SubtaskType">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="ERROR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="REVIEW"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:complexType final="#all" name="CatalogArtistArray">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" nillable="true" type="CatalogArtist"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType final="#all" name="GenericWorkItemArray">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" nillable="true" type="GenericWorkItem"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="securityToken" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="input" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="fingerprint" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="workItemFilter" nillable="true" type="WorkItemFilter"/>
            <xs:element name="xmlErrorWorkItemResultSet" nillable="true" type="XmlErrorWorkItemSearchResultSet"/>
            <xs:element name="name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="sortName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="artistCategory" nillable="true" type="ArtistCategory"/>
            <xs:element name="amgId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="insertArtistResponse" nillable="true" type="CatalogArtist"/>
            <xs:element name="getPriorityCountResponse" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="dupWorkItemResultSet" nillable="true" type="DupWorkItemResultSet"/>
            <xs:element name="workItemIds" nillable="true" type="ns0:intArray"/>
            <xs:element name="version" nillable="true" type="ns0:stringArray"/>
            <xs:element name="applicationName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="comp" nillable="true" type="Component"/>
            <xs:element name="priority" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="watchPointId" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="relativePath" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="result" nillable="true" type="SubmitResult"/>
            <xs:element name="dupWorkItemId" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="dupMatchId" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="conflictNote" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="workItemId" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="errorItem" nillable="true" type="ns0:stringArray"/>
            <xs:element name="qcWorkItemResultSet" nillable="true" type="QCWorkItemResultSet"/>
            <xs:element name="searchName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="findArtistsResponse" nillable="true" type="CatalogArtistArray"/>
            <xs:element name="reevaluateDupResponse" nillable="true" type="ReevaluateDupResultSet"/>
            <xs:element name="xmlContent" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

TBC

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot seem to attach the full wsdl, as it is over 7000 characters long

Comment: The error I run into is "The custom tool 'MSDiscoCodeGenerator' failed. Unable to import binding 'ingestionSoapBinding' from namespace 'http://ingestion.webservice.com/'.

Comment: You can paste the full source into http://pastebin.com and then post the link here.  I think the full wsdl will be necessary to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I was using visual studio with the .net framework 2.0.  This causes an issue as it is unable to handle the newer schemas presented by later versions of apache.  I've been able to upgrade my visual studio projects to .net 4.0 and get "Service" references to my upgraded apache services.  It means there is a bit of busy work, as the interfaces change slightly on how you make the call (.net 4.0 has a call wrapper object).

Comment: Also after doing the upgrade I also found that I needed to set the target namespaces for the objects I had @XmlType on.  @XmlType(namespace="www.foo.com/entities")  this resolved a namespace collision which the wsdl was generating.